# UUID array declared in stored procedure, on access throws explicit type casts needed

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10, uuid

I have a stored procedure where I have declared an array of UUIDs, on using that variable, it throws casting exception.

```
create or replace function test.test_function(max integer, interval interval) returns SETOF test.test_table
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    min TIMESTAMP;
    max TIMESTAMP;
    array_of_guids uuid[];
BEGIN
    array_of_guids = ARRAY(SELECT guid FROM test.test_table WHERE guid NOT IN (SELECT guid FROM test.ignore_test));
    ...

END
$$;
```

The guid is of type UUID, but at this line, I get an error which says:

````
[2019-09-27 12:12:48] Where: PL/pgSQL function test.test_function(integer,interval) line 10 at assignment```

Unable to figure out the syntax to fix the above problem.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the assignment operator to `:=` or use `select into`

```
create table t (id uuid);
insert into t values 
('672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe'::uuid),
('672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe'::uuid),
('672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe'::uuid),
('672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe'::uuid);
```

```
create or replace function test_array2()
returns uuid[] as
$$
declare
    ar uuid[];
begin
    select array_agg(id) from t into ar;
    return ar;
end
$$
language plpgsql;

select * from test_array2();
```

```
create or replace function test_array3()
returns uuid[] as
$$
declare
    ar uuid[];
begin
    ar := array(select array_agg(id) from t);
    return ar;
end
$$
language plpgsql;

select * from test_array3();
```

> ```
> ✓
>
> | test_array3                                                                                                                                             |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | {{672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe,672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe,672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe,672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe}} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=146fb9dd7945aa776061eab379a79ad6)*

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a ton :). Also fiddle - new thing, that's so good! Helps me really well!